# On ajax option partial view is loading on new window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

Index View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

@Ajax.ActionLink("Display", "Dis", new AjaxOptions {

    HttpMethod = "Get",
    UpdateTargetId = "DivDis",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})

<div id="DivDis" >

</div>
```

ABC Controller

```
public class ABCController : Controller
{
    // GET: ABC
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public PartialViewResult Dis()
    {
        return PartialView ("_DD");
    }
}
```

DD Partial view

```
<h1> Hiii </h1>
```

Now when I click on actionlink instead of loading partial view on same page it loads in new page. I want to load my partial view on same page.

Comment: Because you are have not included `jquery..unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: Thanks!  I got confused between jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js. I'd try to not to do such silly mistakes again.